# How to show that $ν(z)$ is Carleson measure

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

If $ν(z)=|1+z|^ β dμ(z)$, $β\in \!\ R^-$. How to show that $ν(z)$ is Carleson?

> > I know that $ν$ is Carleson measure if $ν(Q_I)\leqq \!\ c.I$
> >
> > But how to apply this?